# vector constraint mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I'm doing an optimization and I'm having trouble specifying vector constraints:

```
FindMinimum[{PortfolioVariance, {Total[WeightsVector] == 1}}, WeightsVector];
```

But when I add a constraint to the vector:

```
MV = FindMinimum[{PortfolioVariance, {Total[WeightsVector] == 1, 
And@@WeightsVector[Subscript[w, {#}] > 0 & /@ Range[9]]}}, WeightsVector];
```

I can't get it to work. I just get my input as the output.

My goal is to restrict each item in the vector with an inequality.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already defined WeightsVector previously in your code? If so then show that definition. Do you absolutely have to use subscripts in this?

Comment: Here is the declaration, WeightsVector = Subscript[w, #] & /@ Range[n]

I am not opposed to nixing the subscript. I was adapting an example that used subscript and found the added operations confusing.

Comment: Is it possible to use this? WeightsVector = Table[ToExpression["w" <> ToString[n]], {n, 1, 5}]; FindMinimum[{PortfolioVariance, {Total[WeightsVector] == 1 && And @@ Map[# > 0 &, WeightsVector]}}, WeightsVector]

Comment: Wow- well done, sir. I salute your skills. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Bill came up with an excellent solution in the comments:

Is it possible to use this? WeightsVector = Table[ToExpression["w" <> ToString[n]], {n, 1, 5}]; FindMinimum[{PortfolioVariance, {Total[WeightsVector] == 1 && And @@ Map[# > 0 &, WeightsVector]}}, WeightsVector] –  Bill yesterday

```
WeightsVector = Table[ToExpression["w" <> ToString[n]], {n, 1, 5}]; FindMinimum[{PortfolioVariance, {Total[WeightsVector] == 1 && And @@ Map[# > 0 &, WeightsVector]}}, WeightsVector]
```

Thanks Bill